# AFNetworking: how to associate asynchronous JSON request with UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, afnetworking

I need to make some requests for information that will be used to fill the text field of a table view cell.  however that cell may be reused before the request finishes. how can I associate an  AFNetworking GET request with the uitableview cell in such a way as to be able to cancel it in prepareForReuse?

( if I were not using AFNetworking it would be a no-brainer.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why AFNetworking makes a big difference to the question.

My solution is to:

1. Keep the url of the current request in the custom cell.
2. Have a weak reference to the cell in the completion block for the network call and also capture the requested url.
3. Clear the cell's url in preprareForReuse.
4. In the network completion block before updating the cell check that the cell's captured URL still matches the cell's URL if not don't update the cell (just cache the data or update the model object without refreshing the cell).

I would tend to let the network request complete in most cases but if you are using Data Session Tasks you could store the NSURLSessionDataTask in the cell and call `cancel` on it in prepareForReuse. There may be other options in AFNetworking that are not so easy to cancel.

Comment: so you're not actually going to cancel the network request?

Comment: I would tend not to although I am assuming fairly small requests, your situation may be different. The other factor is that there is a good chance that the cell will be scrolled back so storing or caching the completed result would be my normal approach.

Answer (score 0):

If your're associating an AFHTTPRequestOperation with each cell in tableview, you could manage and cancel your GET request like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation;


- (void)prepareForReuse{
  [super prepareForReuse];
  [self.operation cancel];
}
```

AFHTTPRequestOperation is simply a subclass of NSOperation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A UITableViewCell is very temporary. It doesn't refer to a specific line of your table; it will be reused for different lines. Here's what you do:

1. Have a cache for the data that you want to display in your rows.
2. When a cell is created, you try to fill it with data from the cache.
3. If that fails, then you start an asynchronous request.
4. When the asynchronous request succeeds, it deposits its data in the cache. Then it determines which row of the table contains the data that was just downloaded, and reloads the line.
5. Without you doing anything, the OS will ask you to create the cell again, and this time the data is in the cache. Note that the cell could be a totally different one, but displaying the same data.

Note that the row containing the data may be different from the row that contained the data when you started the request. For example, the user might have added or removed items in the table, or changed the sorting order.

Comment: this is the type of  approach that would normally take,  however I'm being pressured into using AFNetworking is a one-stop solution for all things  computational.